# Access 2016 Multi-Select Box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

First: 
I've been handed a rough Access DB with a Form. I need to turn a drop-down box into a multi-select drop down box. It's essentially a list of states. So I want to be able to choose multiple states (CA,WA,FL,PA,etc.) at once.

Second: 
When submitting the form, it writes all the data in the form to a row in the table (obviously). But from the State selector box, I would like the states chosen in that box to show up in one column, separated by commas (CA,WA,FL,PA).

Is this possible?

Comment: This is what's known as 'multi-value' fields in MS Access.  From a pure relational db design standpoint they break lots of paradigms and nearly all RDBMS don't support these if you are ever thinking of migrating your data.  But it gives the functionality you're after. The multi-value fields are basically nested recordsets and can be a bit tricky when setting up queries.

Comment: I think I can use a List Box with Extended Multi-Select enabled, I just don't know how to set it up so the states get written to a column separated by commas.

I know it's not the best practice for databases, but this whole thing is essentially for a bunch of secretaries. And since I'm the only real SQL guy in the company, they asked me for help.

Comment: Requires VBA that loops through the listbox and concatenates to a CSV string. Common topic. Google. When you develop code that has specific issue, post question.